# ambiguous reference to overloaded definition in scala udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following overloaded method which input can be a `Option[String]` or `Option[Seq[String]]`:

```
def parse_emails(email: => Option[String]) : Seq[String] = {
  email match {
    case Some(e : String) if e.isEmpty() => null
    case Some(e : String) => Seq(e)
    case _ => null
  }
}

def parse_emails(email: Option[Seq[String]]) : Seq[String] = {
  email match {
    case Some(e : Seq[String]) if e.isEmpty() => null
    case Some(e : Seq[String]) => e
    case _ => null
  }
}
```

I want to use this method from Spark, so I tried to wrap them as a udf:

```
def parse_emails_udf = udf(parse_emails _)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method parse_emails of type (email: Option[Seq[String]])Seq[String]
and  method parse_emails of type (email: => Option[String])Seq[String]
match expected type ?
def parse_emails_udf = udf(parse_emails _)
```

Is it possible to define a udf which could wrap both alternative?

Or could it be possible to create two udfs with same name each pointing to one of the overloaded options? I tried below approach, but throws another error:

```
def parse_emails_udf = udf(parse_emails _ : Option[Seq[String]])

error: type mismatch;
 found   : (email: Option[Seq[String]])Seq[String] <and> (email: => Option[String])Seq[String]
 required: Option[Seq[String]]
def parse_emails_udf = udf(parse_emails _ : Option[Seq[String]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Option[String]` and `Option[Seq[String]]` have the same erasure `Option`, so even if Spark supported udf overloading it wouldn't work.

What you can do is create one function that accepts anything, then match on the argument and handle the different cases:

```scala
def parseEmails(arg: Option[AnyRef]) = arg match {
  case Some(x) =>
    x match {
    case str: String =>
      ??? // todo
    case s: Seq[String] =>
      ??? // todo
    case _ =>
      throw new IllegalArgumentException()
    }
  case None =>
    ??? // todo
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working. However I am getting this warning: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern Seq[String] (the underlying of Seq[String]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
        case sq : Seq[String] => sq.  Can this bring any additional issue?

Comment: It won't prevent your code from working. What it means is that the `case` cannot easily distinguish between `Seq[String]` and `Seq[SomethingElse]`. If, someday, you want to  make this distinction, you'll have to check the elements of the Seq themselves.